# Xarray change unit in time variable

Tags: python, netcdf, python-xarray

I have a nc file in which the time variable cannot be decoded by the `xarray.open_dataset()` as the unit is in 'days_since_Jan11900', this is the full info from the `days` variable:

```
<xarray.DataArray 'days' (time: 87600)>
array([679352., 679353., 679354., ..., 766949., 766950., 766951.])
Dimensions without coordinates: time
Attributes:
    units:      days_since_Jan11900
    long_name:  calendar_days
```

I have opened the file with `ds = xr.open_dataset('path/tmax_bcc-csm1-1.nc', decode_times = False)`, but now I would like to change the unit of the nc file into something that Python can easily decode. In my case, the time unit is for now days since Jan 01, 0000. It will eventually make it all easier for my analysis.

How can I do that?

Comment: Are you sure the reference date is January 1st, 0000?  Per the CF conventions, year 0000 is not valid in the Julian or Gregorian calendars.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To decode times, xarray searches for variables that contain a `units` attribute of the form `"{time_unit} since {reference_date}"`.  In your case I would override the units attribute on your DataArray, and then decode the times manually:

```
ds.days.attrs["units"] = "days since 0000-01-01"
result = xr.decode_cf(ds)
```

The one caveat, as I commented, is that I suspect the reference date you have is invalid, so decoding the times will likely raise an error.

Comment: This definitely solves the problem. Indeed, an error is thrown when year is set to 0000. But, that is what the integers indicate though.
Do you know, if I can subtract `679352` from all the integers and then just set the units to `'days since 1860-01-01'`?

Comment: Yes, that would be a good approach if you are sure that the first date in the time series is 1860-01-01.

Comment: I am and I made it work. Thanks for your help it was really helpful!